# How to use flexbox auto margin with nested elements?

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is section. I want same margins between heading and list items. Can flexbox helps here?

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
}

h1 {
  background: #bbb;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>This</li>
    <li>is</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>items</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5vpoyaqd/

P.S. Another [option is put](https://jsfiddle.net/5vpoyaqd/2/) `<h1>` into first `<li>`, but question not about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-left: auto` to `li` elements.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
}

h1 {
  background: #bbb;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */ /* no longer necessary */
}

li {
  margin-left: auto; /* new */
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>This</li>
    <li>is</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>items</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: I think this is really smart solution and should be accepted. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden element inside the ul that will behave as the heading

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
}

h1 {
  background: #bbb;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* added */
ul:before {
  content: '';
}
/**/

li {
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>This</li>
    <li>is</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>items</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Hah! Nice hack!

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `display: contents;` on your ul.

It will move li's containment on the same level as you header so the header and list items will participate on the same level of flex calculation.

```css
 section {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1;
}

h1 {
  background: #bbb;
}

ul {
  display: contents;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>This</li>
    <li>is</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>items</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: That's it! But supported approximately nowhere https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents

Answer (score 0):

You can add `flex: 0.3333` to `h1`. This way you're going to stretch 1/3 of the half of the entire `section width`:

```
h1 {
  background: #bbb;
  flex: 0.3333
}
```

Note: `flex: 1` would be half of the `section`.